# Horizontal Alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How can I align the following information,

```
\center
\begin{itemize}
    \item[Name:] S.A.
    \item[Addres:] vancouver, xx
    \item[Activity:] Some activity
    \item[Legal Owner:] Samuel L. Jackson
\end{itemize}
}
```

When I do this, I have this,

[image]

But, my idea is write something like this,

```
                        Name          :      S.A.
                        Address       :      vancouver, xx
                        Activity      :      Some activity
                        Legal Owner   :      Samuel L. Jackson
```

I am completely sure that this was already asked before, but I can't find the link. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @azetina suggested, you can use `tabular` environment. Please consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lP{2cm}l}
Name&: &S.A.\\
Addres&:& vancouver, xx\\
Activity&:& Some activity\\
Legal Owner&:& Samuel L. Jackson\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

**Note:** You could change the middle column width in order to control the space between columns.

Comment: Elaborate on your MWE so that it shows how you can control the space between columns so that the OP can decide how he can implement it. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @azetina, I edit my response.

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to make table in LaTeX. If you like `tikz`, then it can draw table quite flexible!

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
%\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5,yscale=.5]
\path[right=-1cm]
(0,0)  node{Name}
(0,-1) node{Address}
(0,-2) node{Activity}
(0,-3) node{Legal Owner};
\path
(1,0)  node{:}
(1,-1) node{:}
(1,-2) node{:}
(1,-3) node{:};
\path[right]
(2,0)  node{S.A.}
(2,-1) node{Vancouver, xx}
(2,-2) node{Some activity}
(2,-3) node{Samuel L. Jackson};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```